# Add aesthetics to the text label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
ss <- sample(1:32, 15)
df <- mtcars[ss, ]

ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red') +
  geom_label(aes(x = 2, y = 15), label = 'My Text', size = 10, label.size = 2, label.padding = unit(0.95, "lines"), fill = 'red', alpha = 0.50, color = 'black', label.r = unit(0.45, "lines"))
```

WHile it is working fine, I want add a few more aesthetics as follow

1. Want to add some transparency in the label background. I used alpha = 0.50, but it does not seem to be working
2. Want to have different colour for the border
3. Want to place the label at the top-left position of my graph with some top and left margin e.g. 5 unit.

Is there any way to achieve them? Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the transparency is that you add a label for each row in your data (In the upcoming version of `ggplot2` you will get a message about that), i.e. 15 slightly transparent objects plotted of each other look as is there is no transparency applied. Hence, if you just want one label use `annotate` or use a one row data frame in `geom_label/text`. Concerning your third issue, if you want to place annotations in relative coordinates I would suggest to use `annotation_custom`, which however requires to pass your label as a grob. Unfortunately the `labelGrob` used for `geom_label` is not exported by `ggplot2`. Instead I switched to `gridtext::richtext_grob` (which is the grob powering the `ggtext` package). As an additional benefit this already adds more options for customization, e.g. you can set different colors for the outline and the text. Note that to apply the transparency to the fill color I used `scales::alpha`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
ss <- sample(1:32, 15)
df <- mtcars[ss, ]

ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  annotation_custom(
    gridtext::richtext_grob(
      text = "My Text",
      x = unit(0, "npc") + unit(5, "pt"),
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(5, "pt"),
      hjust = 0,
      vjust = 1,
      padding = unit(0.95, "lines"),
      r = unit(0.45, "lines"),
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = "black"
      ),
      box_gp = grid::gpar(
        col = "blue",
        lwd = 2 * .pt,
        fill = scales::alpha("red", .5)
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
In addition to @stefan answer, a quick workaround could be using two geoms, one overlapping the other.

```
ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = 'red') +
  geom_label(
    aes(x = min(df$wt + 0.1), max(df$mpg) - 1), 
    label = 'My Text', 
    size = 5,
    color = 'green', #border color
    label.size = 1,  #border width
    label.padding = unit(1, "lines"),
    fill = 'red',  #Background color
    alpha = 0.03,  #Transparency of the entire label
    label.r = unit(0.2, "lines"))+
  geom_label(
    aes(x = min(df$wt + 0.1), max(df$mpg) - 1), #same values
    label = 'My Text',
    color = 'blue', #text color
    size = 5,
    alpha = 0,
    label.size = NA, #no border.
    label.padding = unit(1, "lines"),
    label.r = unit(0.1, "lines")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. But this also has issues like I can't adjust padding, border colour and size etc